# Почему зависает Composer на одном и том же пакете?

Tags: php, linux, composer

Устанавливаю зависимости через Composer. На одном и том же пакете всё зависает, после того как он скачивается 100%

[image: Установка зависимостей Composer]

Пробовал команды composer install, composer update, composer cache clear (или как то так). Пробовал перезапускать apache. Ничего не выходит. Что примечательно, зависание всегда происходит не на всех а только на избранных пакетах. В данном случае с sonata-project/admin-bundle.

После этого зависания невозможно перейти в каталог с композером, приходится перезапускать сервер, иначе когда я ввожу команду cd /var/www/site.ru то консоль зависает.

По фтп после зависания попасть в этот каталог тоже не могу.
Также делал composer self-update, не помогло.
xDebug отключен.
Пробовал удалять composer.lock файл.

Использую Vagrant 1.7.4, VirtualBox 5.0.4, PHP 5.5

### UPD

Выполнил `php composer.phar update --prefer-dist -vvv --profile >./composer.log.txt`

Результат

```
[4.0MB/0.02s] Reading ./composer.json  
[4.1MB/0.06s] Loading config file /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/auth.json  
[4.1MB/0.06s] Loading config file ./composer.json  
[4.1MB/0.06s] Loading config file /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/auth.json  
[4.6MB/0.10s] Executing command (/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc): git describe --exact-match --tags  
[4.9MB/0.13s] Executing command (/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v  
[4.9MB/0.14s] Executing command (/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc): hg branch  
[4.9MB/0.15s] Executing command (/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc): svn info --xml  
[9.1MB/0.52s] Loading composer repositories with package information  
[9.6MB/0.54s] Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json  
[9.6MB/1.48s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache  
[9.7MB/1.49s] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)  
[608.4MB/287.14s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/plugin-history%249fb8b47b7f94be913bba1ba67f8700826ceb049e384e488331a16e1deee390bd.json
[611.2MB/288.42s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-history.json into cache  
[608.6MB/289.00s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/plugin-log%2426ae2a0de0f55b7866f4472a0bb38d1a8860127471f9676c3658dc22da39858a.json  
[611.4MB/289.66s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-log.json into cache
[608.9MB/290.26s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/plugin-mock%246b5d6f18527a31ceeffbb8ce59db2c13344eb6ddeda9f816d0c5c4e193d1e442.json  
[611.7MB/290.87s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-mock.json into cache  
[609.1MB/291.52s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/plugin-oauth%2495f85730c5112ec102672f7ca1cc29006c5216983c92621ca8e388546a406f83.json  
[611.9MB/292.88s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-oauth.json into cache  
[609.4MB/294.19s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/service%240d718aff2c0dfebe1b02551cd4ba1cd6f0a53673b29c2a3e382e69f831d43d03.json  
[611.8MB/294.77s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$service.json into cache  
[609.6MB/295.34s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/plugin-md5%24523ca4935b17de3079990d721b2306e299458ec7dce9d279b22e39f8179f28d3.json  
[612.4MB/296.38s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-md5.json into cache  
[610.4MB/297.25s] Downloading http://packagist.org/p/guzzle/plugin-error-response%24c3487442e2e25a0621004bec41f73e97d10903e2acb1012aa9fd604522d66555.json
[612.0MB/297.64s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-error-response.json into cache  
[742.9MB/308.34s] Analyzed 7984 packages to resolve dependencies  
[742.9MB/308.34s] Analyzed 319351 rules to resolve dependencies  
[743.0MB/308.36s]  - Installing sonata-project/admin-bundle (2.3.7)  
[743.4MB/308.38s] Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/zipball/41efdd80e18abd793fe4d1d7d936b2d5f5d8d6d8  
[743.4MB/308.38s] [749.1MB/321.86s]     Downloading: 100%[749.1MB/321.86s]
[749.1MB/321.86s] 321.86s]  
[743.4MB/323.46s] Writing /var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/cache/files/sonata-project/admin-bundle/41efdd80e18abd793fe4d1d7d936b2d5f5d8d6d8.zip into cache  
[743.4MB/325.03s] Extracting archive  
[743.4MB/325.03s] Executing command (CWD): unzip '/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/9ba909f62adfe505acbf66a9d470066d' -d '/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/vendor/composer/64c9a210' && chmod -R u+w '/var/www/ng.podzamenu.loc/vendor/composer/6
```

Выполнил `uname -a`

```
Linux local 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

И `php -v`

```
PHP 5.5.29-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 (cli) (built: Sep  8 2015 12:58:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Выполните php composer.phar update --prefer-dist -vvv --profile >./composer.log.txt и дайте лог

Comment: @ExileeD Сделал. Обновил вопрос. В файл composer.log.txt ничего не записалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл проблему тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917768/why-composer-install-timeouts-after-300-seconds/33559300#33559300

Оказалось что проблема была в NFS, который зависал. Видимо из за того, что composer писал кеш при установке в директорию NFS, который зависал при синхронизации. Вынесение композера глобально, решает проблему тем что начинает записывать кеш не в директорию NFS, а глобально.

Решение написал там же в самом конце.